# Moving Data into a CSV from unstructured TXT file

Tags: python

I am trying to use python to put all of this market research data into an csv file, currently it is in an unstrcutred txt file.

```
Big Hit Entertainment is among the top media & adtech startups for 2020

Big Hit Entertainment is a South Korean entertainment company that currently manages soloist Lee Hyun and idol group BTS. It helps bring the music and content from various sources in one place on its innovative platform.

Founded Year: 2005
Headquarters: Seoul, Seoul-t’ukpyolsi, South Korea
Website: www.ibighit.com
Twitter: www.twitter.com/bighitent
Founders: Bang Si-Hyuk

One97 Communications is among the top media & adtech startups for 2020

One97 is a startup that delivers mobile content and commerce services to millions of mobile consumers. It does so through India’s most widely deployed telecom applications cloud platform.

Founded Year: 2000
Headquarters: Noida, Uttar Pradesh, India
Website: www.one97.com
LinkedIn: www.linkedin.com/company/one97-communications-limited
Twitter: www.twitter.com/One97
Founders: Vijay Shekhar Sharma

Woowa Bros is among the top media & adtech startups for 2020

WOOWA BROS is a Korean developer of smartphone applications and advertising platforms. Amongst other services, their portfolio also includes local marketing and web services solutions and products. Some of these are sports events app and a food delivery app.

Founded Year: 2011
Headquarters: Seoul, Seoul-t’ukpyolsi, South Korea
Website: www.woowahan.com
LinkedIn: www.linkedin.com/company/woowa-bros-
Twitter: www.twitter.com/smartbaedal
Founders: Bong Jin Kim

Wochit is among the top media & adtech startups for 2020

Wochit is revolutionizing the short-form video platform. The cloud-based video creation platform helps brands and storytellers to instantly react to any story and economically scale branded studio-quality video production.

Founded Year: 2012
Headquarters: Yehud, HaMerkaz, Israel
Website: www.wochit.com
LinkedIn: www.linkedin.com/company/wochit
Twitter: www.twitter.com/wochit
Founders: Dror Ginzberg, Ran Oz

Pixellot is among the top media & adtech startups for 2020

Pixellot is a leading sports media company. They provide automatic production solutions for the amateur and semi-professional market. With their patented technology, this startup is able to streamline the production workflow by deploying an unmanned multi-camera system that covers the entire field. The company also makes use of advanced algorithms to enable dynamic coverage of the flow of play and highlight generation.

Founded Year: 2013
Headquarters: Petah Tiqwa, HaMerkaz, Israel
Website: www.pixellot.tv
LinkedIn: www.linkedin.com/company/pixellotltd
Twitter: www.twitter.com/pixellotltd
Founders: Gal Oz, Miky Tamir

Maimai is among the top media & adtech startups for 2020

Maimai is a China-based career and social-networking platform. In just a  few years since its launch, the company has gathered tens of millions of users and surpasses LinkedIn in China for most used professional social networking sites.

Founded Year: 2013
Headquarters: Beijing, Beijing, China
Website: www.maimai.cn
Founders: Fan Lin
```

I want to get it in a format so that the name of each company is the row title, and the column titles are

- Description
- Founded year
- Headquarters
- Website
- Founders

I am confused on where I should go from this point or if there are resources out there already. Thank you!

NOTE: This is not the entire txt file, just a segment.

EDIT:
What is I was to have a txt like this? These two solutions don't seem to work when the structure differes.

```
NestAway is one of the top proptech startups for 2020

This Bangalore-based startup is a home rental network that aims to provide better rental solutions via design and technology. Their motto is to assist customers in booking, finding, and moving into a rental home of choice across Indian cities. All of this is made possible within an application. They also help their customer’s move-in, ask for services from tap leakage to door lock broken, rental payment, etc. Alongside this, they also assist customers in moving out. Here is some more information about this venture, one of the top proptech startups for 2020.

Founding Year: 2015

Headquarters: Bangalore, India

Website: www.nestaway.com

LinkedIn: www.linkedin.com/company/9334060/

Founders: Amarendra Sahu, Deepak Dhar, Jitendra Jagadev, Smruti Parida



Ucommune is one of the top proptech startups for 2020

This startup offers co-working space solutions. They also have provision for long-term leasing, hot desk, and corporate customization and professional solutions. They provide services to small-to-medium enterprises across China, Singapore, New York City, San Francisco in California, and London in the United Kingdom. Here is some more information about this venture, one of the top proptech startups for 2020.

Founding Year: 2015

Headquarters: Beijing, China

Website: www.ucommune.com

LinkedIn: www.linkedin.com/company/ucommune

Founders: Mao Daqing
```

Comment: What do you mean by row title?

Comment: The first box of each row is the title of the company

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luckily the text file has a structure that we can use to tell when each record starts. The trick is to just accumulate description lines until the metadata "Founded Year" shows up. At that point we can grab key/value pairs from the following rows that contain a colon and assume that the record ends when those k/v pairs end.

**EDIT**

This can be a whack-a-mole-game where you have to tweak the conditions to make up for inconsistencies in the text. In the end, they may be too great to account for and the text would have to be "normalized" by hand. I added a second check to make up for differences in the "founding year" key to fix this one.

```
import csv

def text_to_csv(infile, outfile):
    fields = ["Description", "Founded Year", "Headquarters",
        "Website", "Founders"]

    with open(infile) as in_file, open(outfile, 'w', newline='') as out_file:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(out_file, fieldnames=fields)
        writer.writeheader()
        row={}
        description = []
        for line in in_file:
            line = line.strip()
            if not line:
                continue
            # read in description til metadata found
            if not line.startswith("Founded Year: ") and not line.startswith("Founding Year"):
                description.append(line)
                continue
            # metadata found.
            row["Founded Year"] = line.split(";", 1)[1].strip()
            for line in in_file:
                line = line.strip()
                if not line:
                    continue
                try:
                    key, val = line.split(":",1)
                    key = key.strip()
                    if key in fields:
                        row[key] = val.strip()
                except ValueError:
                    break
            # end of metadata
            if row and description:
                row["Description"] = " ".join(description)
                writer.writerow(row)
            row = {}
            description = []
```

text_to_csv("test.txt", "test.csv")
print(open("test.csv").read())

If the structure seen in this sample doesn't hold throughout the document, it will end in tears.

Comment: Great!. This works for the list I put up, but I get the error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 3709: character maps to <undefined> When applying to the whole list.

Comment: Hmmm, My system defaults to UTF-8 and the posted text worked for me... but that could be because stackoverflow itself is encoded that way. As a first step, add `encoding="UTF-8"` to both of the opens. If that doesn't work, then these files may be encoded in a local windows code page. In that case, use your system's code page for the encoding.

Comment: The posted code worked for me as well, but when using the whole list, I get that issue. Could there have been invalid characters? The list was copied from a website.

Comment: Actually I just realized it was only an issue with the print statement!

Answer (score 2):

My answer is similar to @tdelaney's, but uses regular expressions to achieve the task. Python's [regular expressions library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) gives powerful ways to look for specific patterns in unstructured text.

```
import re

def text2csv(inname, outname):
    with open(inname, 'r') as f:
        data = f.read().strip().replace('\n', '\t').replace(',', '') 

    info = re.findall(r'\t(.*?)\ is\ (.*?\t\t.*?)\t\t.*?Founded Year:\ (.*?)\tHeadquarters:\ (.*?)\tWebsite:\ (.*?)\t.*?\tFounders:\ (.*?)\t', data, re.MULTILINE)

    with open(outname, 'w') as f:
        f.write('Name,Description,Founded Year,Headquarters,Website,Founders\n')

        for i in info:
            f.write(','.join(i).replace('\t', '') + '\n')
```